# Uploading app - Error getting android:icon atribute

Tags: android, google-play

I'm having this problem when I try to upload my app to Google Play:

> Failed to run aapt dump badging:
>   W/ResourceType(32467): No known package when getting value for resource number 0x01080051
>   ERROR getting 'android:icon' attribute: attribute is not a string value

I have been searching and I know this issue can be caused by the strings file. I found [this page](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/148691/upload-apk-rror-getting-androidicon-attribute-attribute-is-not-a-string-value) but I can't follow the second part because in the first step, I don't get the "type" and the "entry"...

I don't know what should I do... Thanks for help!!

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <activity
        android:name="com.extremeye.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.extremeye.VisualizadorActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_visualizador"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:icon="@drawable/void_icon"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.extremeye.SeleccionActivity"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_set_as"
        android:label="@string/title_seleccion"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.extremeye.InfoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_info"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: @dymmeh it is copied now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the app icon in my manifest: android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" had corresponding files under /res/drawable-small, /res/drawable-normal, /res/drawable-large and /res/drawable-xlarge but not under /res/drawable. Looks like the automated process of Google Play only looks up /res/drawable. Copying the app icon into this directory.

Comment: Thanks for help, but it doesn't work... I copied the icon into a new folder called drawable on /res but it still not working... I've just copied my manifest into my question if it can help.

Comment: Just put a 96x96 one app icon (in uour case-ic_launcher icon) into drawable folder and removed this icon from all other drawable- folders(xdpi mdpi and others).

Comment: Okay!! I got it!! I'm not sure about what was, I think that was a problem on the manifest, but now it works. Thanks!!