# ERROR getting 'android:icon' attribute: attribute is not a string value while uploading apk to playstore

Tags: android, upload, android-manifest, apk

I've receive that message :

[image]

My AndroidManifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="..."
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-feature
 android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
 android:required="true">
</uses-feature>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
              android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:name="..."
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name="..."
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
      <activity
        android:name="..."
        android:label="@string/label_add_new_object"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow"
        android:theme="@style/MyFancyTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>

       <activity
        android:name="..."
        android:label="@string/label_settings_activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        >
    </activity>


    <activity
            android:name="..."
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@android:color/transparent"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarStyle">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                   android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

    </activity>



</application>
```

As I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800633/getting-androidicon-attribute-attribute-is-not-a-string-value-error-while), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105373/uploading-app-error-getting-androidicon-atribute) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452008/android-market-publishing-androidicon-attribute-attribute-is-not-a-string-v), I've done : 
1) copied all the drawables from @android/drawable to my corresponding folders hdpi, mdpi, e.t.c - 
so I havn't any icon from @android/drawable folder in the project
2) put the icon drawable to the drawable folder of the res 
3) cleaned the project

What can be solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is linked to having the icon attribute setting to a color @android:color/transparent. Maybe try a transparent drawable rather than a color.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution - it was in

```
  <activity
          ....

            android:icon="@android:color/transparent" - the problem string
         ...
    </activity>
```

when I removed that string, everythins worked fine